# Saving multiple linear regression models in a loop

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, linearmodels

I am trying a multi linear regression with 4 independent parameters which are compared against these parameters for a class with label 0 to linearly fit the model.

```
from sklearn import linear_model
from pandas import DataFrame

covariates = DataFrame({'Param1':P1, 'Param2':P2, 'Param3':P3, 'Param4':P4}).iloc[cov_idx, :]
covariates = covariates.to_numpy(dtype=np.float32)

covCN = covariates[labels['Group'] == 0] # only controls as reference group to estimate effect of covariates
lm = linear_model.LinearRegression()

for k in range(images.shape[3]):
  for j in range(images.shape[2]):
    for i in range(images.shape[1]):
      if any(images[:, i, j, k, 0] != 0):
        tmpdat = images[labels['Group'] == 0, i, j, k, 0]
        lm.fit(covCN, tmpdat)
        pred = lm.predict(covariates) 
        images[:, i, j, k, 0] = images[:, i, j, k, 0] - pred
```

I want to save the models of linear regression to predict on a different data set having similar parameters.
When I tried the below code to save the model, I figured that only one model is getting saved.

```
import pickle
with open("model","wb") as f:
  pickle.dump(lm,f)
with open("model","rb") as f:
  model = pickle.load(f)
```

```
covariates = DataFrame({'Param1':A1, 'Param2':A2, 'Param3':A3, 'Param4':A4}).iloc[cov_idx, :]
covariates = covariates.to_numpy(dtype=np.float32)

for k in range(images.shape[3]):
  for j in range(images.shape[2]):
    for i in range(images.shape[1]):
      if any(images[:, i, j, k, 0] != 0):
        pred = model.predict(covariates) 
        images[:, i, j, k, 0] = images[:, i, j, k, 0] - pred
```

How do I save all the linear regression models and use it to predict on the different dataset?

Comment: Where are these independent parameters? You have created just one LogisticRegression model with the default parameters

Comment: I am fetching the parameters from excel sheet, where each columns have different values.
eg. 

```
 Param1     Param2     Param3    Param4
 10                    1           1000             3
 20                    0           2000             2
 30                    1           3000             3
```

Comment: So, the data is different, but the model is the same. Why do you want to save different models then?

Comment: Basically I want to do the process done in the 1st block of code where I fit and model and predict ... to get the same results for the 3rd block of code where I use the coefficients saved from the regression model to predict.

I will need to apply this linear prediction to test on different images with different covariates